# Uniform continuity of characteristic function of a tight family of measure

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-continuity, characteristic-functions

I am missing a step in the proof of Theorem 15.22 of Probabiliy Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version).

The theorem states that, given a tight family of probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, the family of the characteristic functions is uniformly continuous.

I don’t get this first inequality in the proof:

$1-Re(\phi_{\mu}(u)) \\\leq \int |1-\exp(ixu)|\mu(dx)$

Where $|u|$ is “small”.

Any suggestion?

**Edit**

Solution:

$1-Re(\phi_{\mu}(u)) \\
=Re(1-\phi_{\mu}(u))\\
\leq |1-\phi_{\mu}(u)|\\
\leq \int |1-\exp(ixu)|\mu(dx)$

Comment: Your edit answers the question.

Comment: Is the modulus of a complex function greater than the function in the first equality? I’m not sure

Comment: Sure, the real part $x$ of a complex number $z=x+iy$ is always less or equal to the modulus: $x\le |x|=\sqrt{x^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=|z|$.

Comment: So from the first inequality until the end I could remove the “real part” operator, right? Thank you by the way!

Comment: @Enrico No need to repeat in comments, what you already included in your question?

Comment: I thought you suggested to comment instead of post an answer when you down vote me, sorry. I will update the OP. I hope is fine now!